# An error keeps appearing that the sample doesn't work in R Studio cloud and I don't know why

Tags: r, sampling

```
    sharp_null_thought_experiment <- 
  function() {
    final_data %>% 
      mutate(
        OUTCOME_Z_0 = rnorm(n(), sd = 0.5007117),
        OUTCOME_Z_1 = OUTCOME_Z_0,
        Z = sample(rep(c(0, 1), times = c(sum(final_data$treatment_group=="control"), sum(final_data$treatment_group=="treatment"))), size = n()),
        OUTCOME = if_else(Z == 0, OUTCOME_Z_0, OUTCOME_Z_1)
      ) %>% 
      difference_in_means(OUTCOME ~ Z, data = .) %>% 
      
      tidy
  }

    sampling_distribution_sharp_null <- rerun(1000, sharp_null_thought_experiment()) %>%
  bind_rows

sampling_distribution_sharp_null %>%
  summarise(mean(estimate>=results$estimate))
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Edit: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Z`. x cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE' ℹ Input `Z` is `sample(...)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Does `treatment_group` has values other than `"control"` and `"treatment"` ? Maybe an `NA`? Also try Including `replace = TRUE` in `sample`.

Comment: Treatment_group doesn't have any NA values and adding replace = True produces this error: Error in parse_conditions(treatment = data$t, condition1 = condition1, : Must have more than one value in treatment unless using Horvitz-Thompson estimator

Comment: Sorry can't help you further without an example data to test just looking at the code. Please refer to the link in my first comment on how you can share a reproducible example.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help